# combining output of grep command

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

Suppose I have used the grep command :

```
grep 'pattern' 'filename'
```

and have got the result :

```
John
Brown
```

Is there any way to concatenate the outputs into a single one like:

```
John Brown
```

And also is there any way to count the number of outputs and store it in a separate variable?

Comment: Don't be afraid to use the search bar (or click on the links under "Questions that may already have your answer" while entering your question) to see if similar questions have an answer that you can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way -- using `$()` command substitution:

```
echo $(grep 'pattern' 'filename')
```

Edited after the addition of the *count* requirement: Since you presumably have a filename, just run grep again with the --count option:

```
count=$(grep --count 'pattern' 'filename')
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that there's an outside chance you're using a `grep` that does not have the -c (--count) option, in which case a common way to count matches is to use "wc -l", eg: `count=$(grep 'pattern' 'filename' | wc -l)`